# How do I prevent Image.network from caching in between requests

Tags: flutter

How do you prevent Flutter's `Image.network` from caching?

I am trying to load random images from unsplash with it using one URL that returns a new Image on every query but it is only giving me the same one. Hence I think `Image.network` is caching.
I wrote this dartpad gist that illustrates the problem:

https://dartpad.dev/3ffc6011cedea9521997cf83bbfeb9c8

You'll notice it loads the same image three times but that link actually produces a different image on each hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and random number at the end of your request like:

> ```
>   Image.network("https://source.unsplash.com/collection/209138/400x100"),
>   Image.network("https://source.unsplash.com/collection/209138/400x100?2"),
>   Image.network("https://source.unsplash.com/collection/209138/400x100?4"),
> ```

You can randomise the numbers to make sure you always get new images